# Div on bottom of div not working with overflow-y

Tags: jquery, html, css

Base on this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYWDs/) i put the div on the bottom of parent div. how can i make bottom div to be on the bottom when the data inside the parent div overflows.

***Note:***
I only append the bottom div on the append div using append in jquery when the user is typing then remove using the remove

```
<style>
    .container{
        position:relative;
        height:300px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border:1px solid #000;
        width:400px;
    }
    .bottom{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        border:1px solid #C9C9C9; 
        width:100%;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">

    <div class="bottom">picachu is typing</div>
</div> 

<div class="container">
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    <div class="bottom">picachu is typing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it not work if you set `.bottom` as `position: relative;`? Does it have to be inside the container?

Comment: `.bottom{position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px}`  `.container{position:relative}`

Comment: its working on div2 but not on div1

Comment: @Jeemusu `Does it have to be inside the container?`..yup..so does this mean its not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `div.content` to wrap your content and set its `min-height` equal the `.container` height minus `.bottom` height. Then changed `.bottom` position to relative.

Check out [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chokchai/rYWDs/6/)

```
// css 

.bottom{
    position:relative; /* change to relative */
}
.content {
    min-height:278px;
}

// html

div1
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div> <!-- div.content -->
    <div class="bottom">picachu is typing</div>
</div> 
div 2<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"> <!-- div.content -->
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>data<br/>
    <div>
    <div class="bottom">picachu is typing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when the scroll bar appears it overlays on the string..how can i fix this..?

Comment: can you give me a example ?

Comment: OK, That occur because you put the word without spaces so browser  don't know how to chop word for you. It's will not happen in real used, No word are long like that.

Comment: yes i know but still not working with my chatbox with a width of 188 even with word wrap